# Single vs Multiple answers

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Here's a question that has been answered with lists:
[What are must have accessories?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/172/what-are-must-have-accessories)

Is this 'good', or would this be a 'better' way to ask this question:

If you see an accessory you think is a must, then up vote it
If you don't see an accessory you think is a must, add it as an answer.

And make it community wiki.
Then 10 months from now someone can go to this entry and read off the top 5 answers with the most up votes and know that's what most people use.   They can still browse around and see what one off things people have in their bags too, try them out and up vote them later.

Answer (score 4):

This is the type of question asked when someone really wants to ask a question (to try out the site, etc.), but *doesn't* have anything in mind.  They pick upon something related and ask a vague discussion question.  (Discussions are always easy to start, and we humans just love them – it's in our genes.)

Without more specifics, it should simply be closed.

For example, here's my brief attempts at specific questions about accessories, which are still on the discussion side, but have concrete issues that can be addressed:

> #### Accessories for desert photography
>
> I'm going to [Burning Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Man) soon and taking my *[specific type of]* camera.  I'll be staying in a tent and only have room (in the carpooled van) to bring a 1'x2' camera bag.  What accessories will be essential, and why?
>
> What accessories will help protect my other gear from the desert environment?
>
> *[accessories] [harsh-environment] [event-photography] [location-shoot]*
>
> #### Accessories for wedding photography
>
> When doing professional wedding photography, what accessories are essential at the actual event?  I've already planned out *[some specific]* shots which we did at a dedicated shoot.  *[…]*
>
> *[accessories] [wedding-photography] [location-shoot]*

I'm not actually asking these questions on the site because they aren't real questions for me, but *more specific is better.*  Someone really needing an answer (rather than just starting an interesting discussion) should be able to elaborate considerably more.